# Web Bluetooth Won't Detect Devices That were Previously Connected

Tags: google-chrome, web, bluetooth, esp32, web-bluetooth

I'm using web bluetooth to connect to an ESP32 module.

My application is working perfectly on Linux and OSX, but on Windows I'm running into issues.

When doing the initial `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice` call everything works fine -.. However, after a device has been connected and then disconnected web bluetooth fails to see the device again. I'm able to manually search for nearby BLE devices in the control panel and it recognizes the device (discoverable but not connected), but web bluetooth outright fails to see the device.

It seems to be just that Windows computer too -.. When I look for the device on my Mac it's discoverable.

Is there something going on with Windows where previously connected devices aren't discoverable by web-bluetooth?

My connection code is very simple:

```
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(optionalServices:['0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']})
  .then(device => {
    console.log('Connecting...');
    deviceName = device.name;
    return device.gatt.connect();
  })
  .then(server => {
    console.log('Getting Service...');
    return server.getPrimaryService(serviceUuid);
  })
  .then(service => {
    console.log('Getting Characteristic...');
    return service.getCharacteristic(TXcharacteristicUuid).then( characteristic => {
        myTXCharacteristic = characteristic;
        return service.getCharacteristic(RXcharacteristicUuid);
    })
  })
  .then(characteristic => {
    myRXCharacteristic = characteristic;
    return myRXCharacteristic.startNotifications();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('NOOOO! ' + error);
  });
```

Comment: Is this issue permanent (once a device has been connected once it can never be found again) or is the device discoverable again after the browser or computer is restarted?

Comment: It’s permanent we tried restarting the device, computer, emptying chromes cache, etc